# What is mean by sharepoint domain

Tags: sharepoint

I'm trying to do a file transfer from Linux to SharePoint. And I'm confused about what is this Sharepoint.

if https://abctechnologies.sharepoint.com/ Then what is Sharepoint domain

Answer (score 0):

This url is sharepoint online root site. Then correspoding sharepoint domain is *abctechnologies.sharepoint.com* and your Office 365 tenant domain is *abctechnologies.onmicrosoft.com*.

BR